# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'longdescription_title') when page is refreshed

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm pretty new to react, and I am trying to make an Accordion Component with multiple dropdowns. I am trying to load my data from my database. I had thought I got it to work because it showed my data in the correct areas, but when I refreshed the page I got an Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'longdescription_title') error. I'm not sure why this is happening, and I would really appreciate any help or advice on how to fix this problem.
Thank you!

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { detailsProduct } from '../actions/productActions';
import LoadingBox from '../components/LoadingBox';
import MessageBox from '../components/MessageBox';
import '../components/Accordion.css'
import { IconContext } from 'react-icons';
import { FiPlus, FiMinus } from 'react-icons/fi';


export default function ProductScreen(props) {
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const productId = props.match.params.id;
    const [accordionItems, setAccordionItems] = useState([]);
    const [accordionTitles, setAccordionTitles] = useState([]);
    const [clicked, setClicked] = useState(false);
  
  
    const productDetails = useSelector((state) => state.productDetails);
    const { loading, error, product } = productDetails;
    const userSignin = useSelector((state) => state.userSignin);
    const { userInfo } = userSignin;
    
   useEffect(() => {
      if (product) {
          const accordionItems = [product.how_to_use];
          accordionItems.unshift(product.ingredients);
          accordionItems.unshift(product.longdescription);
          setAccordionItems(accordionItems);
      }
  }, [product]);

    useEffect(() => {
      if (product) {
          const accordionTitles = [product.how_to_use_title];
          accordionTitles.unshift(product.ingredients_title);
          accordionTitles.unshift(product.longdescription_title);
          setAccordionTitles(accordionTitles);
      }
  }, [product]);
 

   const Items = [...accordionItems];
   const Titles = [...accordionTitles];
   const accordion = [
      {title: product.longdescription_title, body: product.longdescription},
     {title: product.ingredients_title, body: product.ingredients},
     {title: product.how_to_use_title, body: product.how_to_use},
    ]
    
      
    const toggle = index => {
      if (clicked === index) {
        return setClicked(null);
      }
  
      setClicked(index);
    };
  
    return (
        <div>
            {loading ? (
                <LoadingBox></LoadingBox>
            ) : error ? (
                <MessageBox variant="danger">{error}</MessageBox>
            ) : (
                <div>
                    <Link to="/body">Back to result</Link>
                    <div className="row top">

                        <div className="col-1">
                            <ul>
                                <li>
                                    <h1>{product.name}</h1>
                                </li>
                                
                                <li>
                                  <div>
                                    
                                  <IconContext.Provider value={{ color: 'black', size: '2vw' }}>
                                    <div className="accordionSection">
                                      <div className = "container">
      
                                      {accordion && accordion.length ? (
                                          accordion.map((item, index) => {
                                          return (
                                            <> 
                                              <div className = "wrap" onClick={() => toggle(index)} key={index}>
                                                <h1>{item.title}</h1>
                                        
                                                <span>{clicked === index ? <FiMinus /> : <FiPlus />}</span>
                                              </div>
                                                {clicked === index ? (
                                                <div className="dropdown">
                                                  <p>{item.body}</p>
                                                </div>
                                              ) : 
                                              null}
                                            </>
                                          );
                                        })
                                      ) : (
                                          <></>
                                      )}
                                      </div>
                                    </div>
                                  </IconContext.Provider>
                               
                                 </div>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                      
                                            <li>
                                                <button onClick={addToCartHandler} className="primary block">
                                                    Add to Cart
                                                </button>
                                            </li>
                                        </>
                                    )}
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                            
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    
           
      );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initialize the `Items`, `Titles` and `accordion` variables only when the product has been set (in the `useEffect` calls).
You should use a separate state to store the `accordion` array.
Also, no need to use separate `useEffect` calls:

```
let Items = [];
let Titles = [];

const [accordion, setAccordion] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
  if (product) {
    const accordionItems = [product.how_to_use];
    accordionItems.unshift(product.ingredients);
    accordionItems.unshift(product.longdescription);c
    setAccordionItems(accordionItems);
    Items = [...accordionItems];

    const accordionTitles = [product.how_to_use_title];
    accordionTitles.unshift(product.ingredients_title);
    accordionTitles.unshift(product.longdescription_title);
    setAccordionTitles(accordionTitles);
    Titles = [...accordionTitles];

    setAccordion([
      { title: product.longdescription_title, body: product.longdescription },
      { title: product.ingredients_title, body: product.ingredients },
      { title: product.how_to_use_title, body: product.how_to_use },
    ]);
  }
}, [product]);
```

Comment: @Luca_Pizzini Hi, okay, I tried doing that, but now my accordion component isn't showing on the screen.

Comment: @Gigi101 Check edited answer

Comment: @Luca_Pizzini Okay, that makes sense. Thank you!